# MongoDB Java - How to assign variables from a document

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there a way to store a variable from a document in MongoDB? Say you have this document:

```
{
    "math" : {
        "variableone" : 3,
        "variabletwo" : 4,
    }
}
```

I would like to assign the data to int variables and add the two and print out the sum.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is to write a  Class that represents your document:

```
public class Math {

    private int variableone;
    private int variabletwo;

    //getters & setters

}
```

You can then use Jackson [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert the document string into an object of the class Math.